# Comparing 3 SQL Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to compare 3 tables with 1 being the base table.

So here are my 3 table(s) where Table 1 is the base table and the other two are compared with each other.

```
Table1
ID   | ChargeItem
-----------------
5055 | Item1
5056 | Item2
5057 | Item3
5058 | Item4
5059 | Item5
5060 | Item6
5061 | Item7
5062 | Item8
5063 | Item9
5064 | Item10
5065 | Item11

Table2                                         
ID | membershiprecordid | ChargeItemID | Status
-----------------------------------------------
1  | 268765             | 5060         | 1     
2  | 268765             | 5060         | 1     

Table3
ID    | ChargeItemID
--------------------
12146 | 5058
12146 | 5060
12146 | 5062
12146 | 5063
12146 | 5065
```

Here is my SQL query so far

```
SELECT Table1.ID
FROM Table1 as T1 
WHERE T1.ID NOT in (
     select Table2.chargeitemid from Table2 as T2 
     right join Table3 as T3 on T2.chargeitemid = T3.chargeitemid
     where T2.membershiprecordid = 268765 AND T2.[Status] = 2
)
```

So In the SQL query I am trying to get back IDs from `Table 1` where it doesn't exist in `Table 2` and `Table 3`. And Inside my sub query I compare `Table 2` and `Table 3` where by `Table 2` taking priority over `Table 3` so if a ChargeItemID exists in `Table 2` with `Status = 2` then fetch it and return its ID along with the ID's in the `Table1`

Currently it doesn't return any ID's for `Table 1`? Any suggestions as to why?

The Result should be the following ChargeItem ID's returned from `Table1`

`5055`, 
`5056`, 
`5057`, 
`5059`, 
`5061`, 
`5064`

Hopefully it explains my issue?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Please ignore `T2.ClubID = 1600` it was posted in error

**UPDATE 2**

Expected result from the query

Comment: What is T2.clubid = 1600 and T2.membershiprecordid = 268765 ?

Comment: When you say doesn't exist in table 2 and table 3 do you mean it could exist in one, but not both, or it shouldn't exist in either?

Comment: Please post your sample data as script

Comment: Question updated please ignore `T2.Clubid = 1600` it was posted in error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below query to find out id's which are present on Table1 and not present on Table2 & table 3.

```
    CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (ID INT);
    INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (5055), (5056), (5060), (5065), (5057);

    CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (ID INT, CHARGEITEMID INT, STATUS INT)
    INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (1, 5060,1)
    INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (2, 5065,1)
    INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (2, 5056,2)

    CREATE TABLE TABLE3 (ID INT, CHARGEITEMID INT )
    INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (1, 5058)
    INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (1, 5060)
    INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (1, 5062)
    INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (1, 5063)
    INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (1, 5065)
    INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (1, 5056)


    select * from TABLE1
    select * from TABLE2
    select * from TABLE3

    select id
    from TABLE1
    except
    (
        select CHARGEITEMID from TABLE2
        intersect
        select CHARGEITEMID from TABLE3
    )
```

Comment: However I posted my solution above, but your answer gave me a more accurate result. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if this accomplish your request (Maybe I didn't understood it very well):

```
SELECT T1.ID
FROM Table1 as T1 
LEFT JOIN (select DISTINCT T3.chargeitemid, T2.STATUS
           from Table2 as T2 
           right join Table3 as T3 on T2.chargeitemid = T3.chargeitemid
           ) T4 ON T1.ID = T4.CHARGEITEMID
WHERE T4.chargeitemid IS NULL 
     OR T4.Status = 2
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (ID INT);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (5055), (5056), (5060), (5065), (5057);
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (ID INT, CHARGEITEMID INT, STATUS INT)
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (1, 5060,1)
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (2, 5065,1)
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (2, 5056,2)
CREATE TABLE TABLE3 (ID INT, CHARGEITEMID INT )
INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (1, 5058)
INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (1, 5060)
INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (1, 5062)
INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (1, 5063)
INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (1, 5065)
INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES (1, 5056)
```

Output:

```
ID
-----------
5055
5056
5057
```

Comment: Why is there a fourth table? `T4`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a `left join`, that will preserve all rows from `Table1` and give `null` to the columns of `Table2` and `Table3` that are not joined. This way you only need to filter on those fields being `null`.

```
select  t1.id
from    Table1 t1
left join
        Table2 t2
on      t1.ID = t2.ChargeItemID and
        t2.membershiprecordid = 268765 and
        t2.[Status] = 2
left join
        Table3 t3
on      t1.ID = t3.ChargeItemID
where   t2.ChargeItemID is null or
        t3.ChargeItemID is null
```

If, as per @BeanFrog comment, you want the `IDs` that are not available on neither `Table2` nor `Table3`, you can just replace `OR` with `AND` in the `where` clause.

**Edit**

Seems I misunderstood the requirements, this one should do the trick

```
select  t1.id
from    Table1 t1
left join
        Table3 t3
on      t1.ID = t3.ChargeItemID
left join
        Table2 t2
on      t3.ChargeItemID = t2.ChargeItemID
where   t3.ChargeItemID is null or (
            coalesce(t2.membershiprecordid, -1) = 268765 and
            coalesce(t2.[Status], -1) = 2
        );
```

This will return the IDs that are not in t3 or that are in both t3 and t2 (with the t2 filters applied); you can see it in action [here](http://rextester.com/KHCL24695)

Comment: This is not working unfortunately. Seems to return rows that don't exist for `T2.Membershiprecordid = 268765` I have updated question for expected results. `T3` has to be compare with `T2` also

Comment: I can't see the expected results

Comment: I updated the question. The Result should be the following ChargeItem ID's returned from Table1 `5055`, `5056`, `5057`, `5059`, `5061`, `5064`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I edited my answer with a better query and a working example.

Answer (score 0):

try to use not exists, like this

```
    select T1.ID as cid
  from Table1 as T1
 where not exists (select 1 from Table2 as T2 where T2.chargeitemid = T1.ID)
   and not exists
 (select 1 from Table3 as T3 where T3.chargeitemid = T1.ID)
union all
select T2.chargeitemid as cid
  from Table2 as T2
 right join Table3 as T3 on T2.chargeitemid = T3.chargeitemid
 where T2.membershiprecordid = 268765
   and T2.Status = 2
```

Comment: Its bringing back all rows from `Table1` regardless of `Table2` and `Table3` It should only bring back the following Charge ID's from Table `5055`, `5056`, `5057`, `5059`, `5061`, `5064`

Comment: ok !!!, i have changed my query above, please try it and inform me result

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- You mention: "where by Table 2 taking priority over Table 3." If you are performing a RIGHT JOIN, you are essentially saying that Table 3's rows should be shown regardless of whether there is a match in Table 2. Here, "RIGHT" indicates the table you are joining to, which is Table 3.
- When you include a WHERE clause and a RIGHT JOIN, you are essentially negating the RIGHT JOIN and turning this query into an INNER JOIN. What does this mean? Your query will JOIN on the specified columns, then filter the entire search set to match your WHERE clause.
- If you want all columns from Table 2 to be shown when they match the WHERE clause credentials regardless of whether the table can be joined to Table 3, you'll want to change your sub-query to:

  ```
  SELECT Table2.chargeitemid from Table2 as T2 
  LEFT JOIN Table3 as T3 
  ON T2.chargeitemid = T3.chargeitemid
      AND T2.clubid = 1600 
      AND T2.membershiprecordid = 268765 
      AND T2.[Status] = 2
  ```

This query will return all columns from Table 2 where the (T2.clubid = 1600 ...) are met and *only* show columns from table 3 *if* the chargeitemid is matched. This would accomplish "Table 2 taking priority over Table 3."

In addition, does your sub-query (the query inside WHERE T1.ID NOT in) return the expected results? I can update this post as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this resolved by Using SQL `Except` as shown below. So in the query it queries the master table first and gets all the `id`'s. Then I compare the results against the results from `table 2` and `table 3` to get the final list.

```
SELECT id FROM table1
except
SELECT chargeitemid FROM table3
except
SELECT chargeitemid FROM table2 WHERE membershiprecordid = 268765 AND status = 2
```